# how to rename a Bluetooth device Xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have managed to to display discovered devices that I have having trouble with [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956125/xamarian-core-bluetooth) .

My question is how would you go about connecting to one of those devices and renaming it? Help/Example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to rename it, the peripheral has to have a characteristic that can be written and will be used to show its name. If not, you can't rename it.

Comment: A android native app was built and the peripheral was renamed that way I'm sure the characteristic is there. But going about it on Xamarin I'm finding it a little tricky to get started.

Comment: Nothing wrong about Xamarin. It seems that you just don't have the logic on how CoreBluetooth.framework works. Read some tutorial about it, and come back with a specific question. Because, it doesn't seems that you've even managed to read the values for all characteristics.

Comment: Thanks will do that. Have you got any links to some good tutorials?

Comment: Xamarin CoreBluetooth AI Docs: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/CoreBluetooth/ . Xamarin Example (deprecated): https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BluetoothLEExplorer/ . New component that includes Bluetooth usage: https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics